# Given start & stop time, check if service should be on

Tags: python

I need to figure out if a service should be stopped or started given a start and stop time
e.g.

```py
start_time = '16:00'
stop_time = '7:50'
```

if the time now is 16:50 the service should be running, if time now is 14:00, service should be stopped

```py
start_time = '7:00'
stop_time = '20:00'
```

if the time now is 7:05 the service should be running, if the time is 21:00, the service should be stopped... you get the idea

so far I have this, but can't figure out the logic ;

```py
import datetime 

def test_time(start_time, stop_time):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_hour = int(now.hour)
    current_minute = int(now.minute)
    start_hour, start_minute = start_time.split(':')
    stop_hour, stop_minute = stop_time.split(':')

    print(f"hour: {current_hour}, minute: {current_minute}")
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `scheduler class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime` to convert your text times to `time`s.  This gives you an interval during which the service should be on.  If that period wraps around midnight, then split it into two intervals.

Then, simply check to see whether the current time is within the `on` period or `off` period; also check the status of the service.  If the two don't match, then start/stop the service.

```
def sync_service(start_time, stop_time):
    # start_time and stop_time are "datetime" items.
    service_on = # Check status of service; return boolean
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # If interval wraps around midnight, then switch times
    #   to check when service is *off*
    wrap_interval = stop_time < start_time
    if wrap_interval:
        start_time, stop_time = stop_time, start_time

    # Should the service be on now?
    # Check whether we're within the daily interval,
    #   and what type of interval we have (on or off)
    want_service_on = wrap_interval != (start_time < now < stop_time)

    # Adjust service status, if necessary
    if want_service_on and not service_on:
        service.start()
    if not want_service_on and service_on:
        service.stop()
```

Does that get you going?